# d3.timer() frame - slowing down

Tags: javascript, d3.js, frame

is it possible to slow down frames in

`d3.timer(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);` ?

Here we have delay of 3 sec and then it becomes very fast.

For example in

`setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);`

we are able to change 3000 milliseconds to 2000 and we will be continuously alert every 2 sec instead of 3.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

API reference of D3-timer says:

> d3.interval(callback[, delay[, time]]) <>
>
> Like timer, except the callback is invoked only every delay
>   milliseconds; if delay is not specified, this is equivalent to timer.
>   A suitable replacement for setInterval that is guaranteed to not run
>   in the background. The callback is passed the elapsed time.

You can find it here: [github](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer)

In your case:

```
d3.interval(function(){ alert("Hello") }, 3000);
```